# I want to trigger an actvity from a fragment using button but i'am getting Unfortunately, app has stopped on button click. where am i doing wrong?

Tags: android

I want to trigger an actvity from a fragment using button but i'am getting Unfortunately, app has stopped on button click. where am i doing wrong?

```
public class Query extends Fragment {

public Query(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.que, container, false);

    final Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Queryy.class);
           ((MainActivity) getActivity()).startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return rootView;

}
```

}

And my que.xml file looks like

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Button" />
```

any ideas? thank you.

Comment: Did you add the activity to your manifest?

Comment: Yes, i did that too. Here's the snippet                
<activity
            android:name="beauty.app.majesticwork.Queryy"
           android:label="@string/app_name" >
          
       </activity>
@SaNtoRiaN

Comment: please mentioned and add here what kind of error is coming in logcat

Comment: Please post your logcat

Comment: Check is your Queryy class extends Activity and is getActivity() method returns not null value.

Answer (score 0):

Try using only

```
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

without the `MainActivity`

Comment: @AkankshaKr hmm, can you add your logcat and the activity Queryy to the post? because the error maybe in the activity not the fragment

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Query.class);
startActivity(intent) is enough.. Try with this
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Queryy.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

startActivity is already defined in fragment.java. Your class has to inherit fragment.java. If you have not inherited, use

```
    startActivityFromFragment
```

Comment: Now i am getting this error: The method startActivityFromFragment(Intent) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Comment: try this. getActivity().startActivityFromFragment(this, intent, -1);
startActivityFromFragment needs more arguments.